# How to get vue JS single file component css into a file and not inline

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component

I'm using vue js single file components, but just realized the css that I'm including in the style section of the component is just added as inline style to the HTML head. Is there a way to have the css from all components into 1 css file, so that it can be cached, rather than inline?

Answer (score 0):

If you want another options for add css in your component vue, you can create a css file inside your components folder who have the same name has your vue file (not an obligation), example :

- myComponent.vue
- myComponent.css

After you just need to import your css file inside your vue file.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I wasn't sure if there was a way to compile all the component inline style into an external js file. That would be a really nice feature to be able to do this through webpack.

Comment: I was wrong, doing the @import, still just adds the css inline in the header in the style tags, then doing a <link href="../css" />. So, I'm still searching for the best way to get css cached and linked to the vue component.